# use jquery to parse xml get child of object

Tags: jquery, xml, rss

Using jQ I am rendering an RSS feed which works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($jQ) {
$jQ.get('URL', function(data) {
   var $jQxml = $jQ(data);
   $jQxml.find("item").each(function() {
    var $jQthis = $jQ(this),
        item = {
            title: $jQthis.find("title").text(),
            link: $jQthis.find("link").text(),
            image: $jQthis.find("description").text()
    }
    console.log(item)
    });
   });
 });
```

I want to grab the src of the image which is a child of a p that is a child of description:

```
<description><![CDATA[<p><img src="image.jpg"/></p>
<p>The post </p>
]]></description>
```

I've tried

```
jQthis.find("description").children("img").attr("src");
```

No luck. Any ideas on how to fetch the img src of this output?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your example of what you've tried needs the leading `$` and quotes around `src`; could that be an issue?

Comment: Thanks but that didn't resolve. I've tried to also do        jQthis.find("description").children("p").text();   which also does not output any value

Answer (score 0):

You have HTML inside of CDATA, so you must first use jQuery's `parseXML()` on your XML string, and then capture the text inside of `description`, which is that string of HTML, and then you must treat that HTML as a new jQuery object.

Try:

```
var $jQxml = $jQ($jQ.parseXML(data));
var $description = $jQ($jQxml.find('description').text()); 
// then:
$description.find('img').attr('src');
```